# Why can't I connect to this server via FTP?

Tags: macos, ftp, filezilla

I'm trying to connect to a server via FTP (to upload a new site). I'm getting the following error message using FileZilla

```
Status: Connecting to xx.xx.xx.xx:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 Microsoft FTP Service
Command:    USER ***********
Response:   331 Password required for speyleis.
Command:    PASS *********
Response:   230 User logged in.
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 Windows_NT
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Extended features supported:
Response:    LANG EN*
Response:    UTF8
Response:    AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
Response:    PBSZ
Response:    PROT C;P;
Response:    CCC
Response:    HOST
Response:    SIZE
Response:    MDTM
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:   211 END
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I.
Command:    PASV
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

The weird part is that my friend (currently in China) can access it no problem. I usually have no problem accessing servers so don't even know why this is being difficult.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FTP LIST command fails between between host OS and guest OS](http://superuser.com/questions/331597/ftp-list-command-fails-between-between-host-os-and-guest-os)

Comment: @techie - I disagree with the above duplicate suggestion. That question gets past the `PASV` command and fails later.

Comment: @nifle You are correct.  I'd undo my vote if I could. :)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like that FTP server may not support Passive Mode FTP (PASV). I would switch your FTP client to Active mode (also known as PORT mode) and see if you can connect.

Comment: Sounds about right. After `PASV`you should usually get something like `Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (1,100,104,22,5,125).`

Comment: If the FTP server does not support a particular command, it should still respond immediately. (PASV is a required part of FTP, however.)

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the FEAT response it seems unlikely that this server simply does not support passive mode.  I wonder if we simply seeing a logging failure where the server's PASV response was simply not written after the client failed to open the data channel... and so the timeout we are seeing is a timeout opening the data channel instead of a timeone on the control channel.

Another possibility is a misconfigured "protocol-aware" firewall.  Some firewalls monitor the FTP control channel and scan for the PORT or PASV commands and then they open the appropriate ports on the fly.  This is great when it works.  If this is on a laptop take it home and see if it works from there.  If it is a desktop at work see if you can find an admin that will let you put it out on the DMZ for a quick test.